# How to save data?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, eloquent

My data is like this

[image: first]

After re-saving the data is saved two double.

[image: second]

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    foreach ($request->name as $key => $name) {
        Setting::firstOrCreate(
            ['name' => $name],
            ['link' => $request->link[$key]]
        );
    }
    return redirect()->route('settings.index');
}
```

Comment: Please share more details, and your debugging attempts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to used [updateOrCreate](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts) method instead of firstOrCreate

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    foreach ($request->name as $key => $name) {
        Setting::updateOrCreate(
            ['name' => $name],
            ['link' => $request->link[$key]]
        );
    }
    return redirect()->route('settings.index');
}
```

for more information read this article https://eloquentbyexample.com/course/lesson/lesson-7-creating-and-updating